# flask handle form with radio buttons

Tags: python-3.x, flask, radio-button

My `index.html` looks like this

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option3 <br>
</p>
<p><input type=submit value=Next></p>
</form>
```

I need to get the selected button. But since they all have the same name I cannot do it by writing `request.form['option']`. If I make their names different, users can make multiple selections.

Isn't there a way to get a button's state by it's id ? If no, what's the simplest way to handle this form ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should add the `value` attribute to each of your `input` fields:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="option1"> Option1 </input><br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="option2"> Option2 </input><br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="option3"> Option3 </input><br>
```

and in your flask route you can read the selected option:

```
option = request.form['options']
```

and you'll get the `value` of the selected radio button.

Comment: I am getting this `400 Bad Request: KeyError:`

Comment: @Sarthak You need to place your buttons under the same HTML form tag as your submit button is.

Answer (score 8):

or an alternative and simple method is to use

> getlist()

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="option1"> Option1 </input<br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="option2"> Option2 </input<br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="option3"> Option3 </input<br>
```

then to get value selected, in your flask file:

```
option = request.form.getlist('options')
```

nb: you can select more or one value it will be saved in a list

Answer (score 4):

To anyone getting a `400 Bad Request: Key Error` type-error, try one of the following:

- Ensure that you are requiring the client to choose an radio option
- Employ a `try/except[/else/final]` statement to handle cases where the client does not choose an option, and you don't require them to choose one

I'd respond to @sarthak 's comment but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score -2):

400 bad request error can come if server is not able to find an element that is named as options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).